# Why I can't access to this list put into the Model object into this Spring MVC project?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following doubt:

Into a controller I have this method that handle HTTP Request toward **/consultazioneMinisteriale** URL

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/consultazioneMinisteriale", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String consultazione(Locale locale, Model model) {

    List<Twb1012Regione> listaRegioni = geograficaService.getListaRegioni();

    return "utenteMinisteriale/consultazione";
}
```

As you can see in the method I retrieve a List of **Twb1012Regione** objects calling a service, I correctly retrieve this object (using debugger I see that is correctly initialized)

Now I want that this list is available into the returned view, so I have changed the previous method in this way:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/consultazioneMinisteriale", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String consultazione(Locale locale, Model model) {

    List<Twb1012Regione> listaRegioni = geograficaService.getListaRegioni();
    model.addAttribute(listaRegioni);
    return "utenteMinisteriale/consultazione";
}
```

So I have simply added the retrieved list to the **Model** object.

Now I am trying to access to this object from my **consultazione.jsp** view, in this way:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@  taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>

    <body class="azure">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>

        <div> ${listaRegioni} </div>

        <c:forEach items="${listaRegioni}" var="item">
            TEST<br>
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it don't work and I can't see no reference of this **listaRegioni** object into my view (it only print the **Hello World** message).

Why? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not really a user of Spring MVC but `model.addAttribute(listaRegioni);` doesn't seem to provide a name for the list so the expression `${listaRegioni}` wouldn't find it. Note that at runtime the name of the local variable is not available anymore. I'd guess you need something like `model.addAttribute("listaRegioni", listaRegioni);` i.e. tell the model to store the attribute list under the name you want to use to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an attribute to the model without a name.

```
model.addAttribute(listaRegioni);
```

So a name is inferred, for this it looks at the types in the collection and adds the the `List` suffix. So the name of the attribute is `twb1012RegioneList` and not `listaRegioni` (as you currently have in your JSP). This is described in the [naming conventions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Conventions.html#getVariableName-java.lang.Object-).

It is better to explicitly name the parameter when adding it to the model.

```
model.addAttribute("listaRegioni", listaRegioni);
```